# Shell script for dynamically generate command

Tags: shell, unix

Below is a sample code:

```
arg[1]="shell"
arg_value[1]=10
agr[2]="script"
agr_value[2]=50

command skbit ${agr[1]}="${arg_value[1]}" ${agr[2]}="${arg_value[2]}"
```

---

*skbit* is a script that accepts arguments in above format.

Now if there are multiple arguments that depends on the run time. How to create above command dynamically.

I tried with,

```
command skbit $str
```

where 
    `str= ${agr[1]}="${arg_value[1]}" ${agr[2]}="${arg_value[2]}"` and so on.

this structure is not working for command for multiple reason.

I want a code of below structure:

```
command skbit {A code which will generate arguments dynamically}
```

Comment: Why `agr` and `arg`? Why `arg_value` and `agr_value`?

Comment: [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Are you maybe looking for something like this:

```
# define some arguments and values
arg[1]=shell
arg_value[1]=10
arg[2]=script
arg_value[2]=50

# joins the arguments and its values
for i in "${!arg[@]}"; do
  args+=( "${arg[i]}=${arg_value[i]}" )
done

# calls the command with the joined arguments
command skbit "${args[@]}"
```

You might also use associative array instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A arg

arg[shell]=10
arg[script]=50

for i in "${!arg[@]}"; do
  args+=( "$i=${arg[$i]}" )
done

command skbit "${args[@]}"
```